# Highcharts: how do I align data labels on the right in a bar chart?

Tags: highcharts

How could I achieve to align the data labels on the left in Highcharts bar charts as showned in the picture below?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just align them left in your settings:

```
 plotOptions: {
   series: {
     dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        inside: true,
        align: 'left'
     }
   }
 }
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3d3fuhbb/200/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.align
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.inside